# unable to take event value from console

Tags: angular, typescript

I am unable to take event total value from console.

console:

```
Object { type: 1, loaded: 1048105, total: 1334347 }
​
loaded: 1048105
​
total: 1334347
​
type: 1
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
app.component.ts:84:20
Object { type: 1, loaded: 1128059, total: 1334347 }
app.component.ts:84:20
Object { type: 1, loaded: 1227405, total: 1334347 }
app.component.ts:84:20
Object { type: 1, loaded: 1334347, total: 1334347 }
```

typescript:

```
onuploadFile( files : File[]): void{
    console.log(files)
    const formData = new FormData()
    for(const file of files){
      formData.append('files', file, file.name)
    }
    this.user.uploadFiles(formData).subscribe({
      next: (event) => {
        switch(event.type){
          case HttpEventType.UploadProgress || HttpEventType.DownloadProgress:
            console.log(event)
            this.filestatus.percentage = Math.round( 100 * event.loaded / event.total) <-- (event.total says object is possibly 'undefined')
            this.filestatus.status = 'progress'
            break;
          case HttpEventType.Response:
            console.log(event)
            this.filestatus.percentage = 0
            this.filestatus.status = 'done'
            break;
        }
      },
      error: (e) => console.log(e),
      complete: () => console.log('done uploading')
    })
  }
```

error:
object is possibly 'undefined'

So how can i divide the the number to get percentage value.

Answer (score 0):

To fully understand what is going on you would need to show us the return type of `this.user.uploadFiles` function, but I'm 100% that the `total` is marked as optional in that type and therefore Typescript compiler raises an error since the `total` can be `null`/`undefined` and in this case you would get a runtime error. Even though you can see `total` being populated in console, there is no guarantee that every object will have it, at least you are communicating that to a compiler with a type of the object you are returning from the `uploadFiles`.

If `total` will always be present in the object then mark it as required
in the type/class/interface which you are returning from `uploadFiles` or  mark the `total` as non-null with [non-null assertion operator (!)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator):

```js
this.filestatus.percentage = Math.round( 100 * event.loaded / event.total!) // ! at the end
```